# nginx vs haproxy in private network

Tags: nginx, haproxy

I am currently using haproxy on my OPNsense. It is currently also set up to serve some internal WebGUIs to pass on the LE wildcard certificate I have for my domain. Mainly stuff like unifi controller, sites that aren't default at HTTP.
But, I am missing WAF, as I used to have on my previous Sophos UTM.
So, I am looking to implement nginx (completely new to it btw).
HAproxy is doing nothing else but listening on the gateway-IP/port of the VLAN where those WebGUIs reside and passes on the cert.

The first and foremost question I have: can nginx do the same? Or do I *have* to go through the WAN?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

nginx has [reverse proxy functionality](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) which will do what you're saying your haproxy is doing so no need to go through the WAN. You haven't made it clear how you're getting your LE wildcard certificate issued (DNS? web?) but if you can get it to haproxy, you should be able to get it to nginx.

Bear in mind that nginx itself is not a WAF although it has WAF modules such as [ModSecurity](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-waf/) and [App Protect](https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx-app-protect/) for which you may be required to pay.

Comment: The LE wildcard cert is being pulled by LE cert plugin in OPNsense, via Cloudflare DNS API.
Yes, it should work, but unfortunately I didn't manage to get it to work. I can get haproxy working without much problems, but no-go with nginx. Possibly nginx needs more manual configuration to make it work...? I don't know.

While you mention WAF... is there something that makes sense to use with Nextcloud when putting it onto internet? It's on an Ubuntu Server, default install, some recommended security policies from Nextcloud, but that's it. OPNsense only isolates through haproxy, custom port.

Comment: It seems that OPNsense has an nginx-based WAF that you can configure through the GUI: https://docs.opnsense.org/manual/how-tos/nginx_waf.html